# How to predict my own images and check if they match using SVM classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I followed a tutorial and trained a model using SVM. When I test the model using its test set it predicts, but I want to upload my own images and compare them if they match and then print the accuracy of the result.

```
img1 = imageio.imread("test-1.jpg")
img2 = imageio.imread("test-2.jpg")
  
myTest = []
myTest.append(img1)
myTest.append(img2)

pred = svc_1.predict(myTest)
```

It shows

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: That would be the size of img1 is not equal the size of img2.

Comment: @EpicChen Is it necessary to resize them to the same size?

Comment: They don't need to in the same size. But myTest array would be restricted the size of each array items after img1 is appended. That means img2 is required the size of each array items the same as img1. Assume img1.shape = (3, 2), img2.shape needs to be (x , 2) where x belongs to positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do the 2 images have the same size?

Second, we need to have a 2D input for the SVC model. So you need to flatten your 3D images and create a feature matrix with dimension [# images, # pixels in image].

Toy example (in reality we need to fit the model using the training set and predict using a test set).

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

img1 = imageio.imread("test-1.jpg")
img2 = imageio.imread("test-2.jpg")
  
y = [0,1] #labels for the classification

myTest = []
myTest.append(np.array(img1).ravel()) # ravel the 3D images into a vector
myTest.append(np.array(img2).ravel())

svc_1 = SVC().fit(myTest,y ) # fit the model
pred = svc_1.predict(myTest) # predict
print(pred)
# [1 1]
```

Comment: Still is the same error in `svc_1 = SVC().fit(myTest, y)`. Do I have to pass some other parameters if necessary?

Comment: The dataset's test set passed from the function is a numpy array and has a shape `10, 4096`. But `myTest` is a list and when I convert it to array it's shape is `2,` I don't know why the pixels are not listed.

Comment: try to type `myTest[0].shape` and `myTest[1].shape`. Are both `10,4096` ?